# How do I convert RESTful POST call to Ajax in Tornado?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, rest, tornado

I am learning Tornado and my app does just following:

- `localhost:8000/add/name` : adds name to the database
- `localhost:8000/delete/name`: deletes name from database

As of now I type in browser address bar `/add/name` and manually adding names.

1. How do I make use of HTML forms for this request? Is this the right way: I create a field box with a id, using JS I get the value from that id, construct the RESTful POST url and on clicking submit, it goes to the constructed url.
2. Now I want to turn above thing to AJAX call so that there is no page refresh. All the examples I found uses form where it sends the 'value' as request parameter not as RESTful.

Any help regarding this is appreciated. Thank you!

PS: I know I can use `get_argument` in Tornado and get the value. But I want this in REST, sending the value in URL.

Comment: no no no no! `/names` is the resource, you `POST` a new name, which will give you a URI back, which you can then `DELETE`. Do not have 'actions' in your URI!

Comment: PS. sending values in the URL (URI) does not make something REST

Comment: oops. I got the whole thing wrong. I will update the question. But then I think its easier to convert to AJAX. cos I will be sending the values in the request body.

Answer (score -1):

`/add/name/(\d)+`
Then make post function with  `def post (self,  id): pass`. this argument id is value in url `\d` pattern. Hope it’s helpful.